# Get information from button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, grid

I have a WPF application with a grid. There are rows and columns, at the end of each row I have a "Click me" button.

How can I get information where pressed button?

I want to display information from row, after the button has been clicked.

Comment: One option is to bind the current row to the CommandParameter property of the button - if you are using MVVM

Comment: If not using MVVM, give each button a name and set up a common event handler that uses the name in the conditional logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to attach all buttons to the same event and then but give them a unique name.

```
private void btn_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button cmd = (Button)sender;
    string name = cmd.name;
    switch(name)
    //{ do some stuff based on the button name}
}
```